# How to check whether some variable returns something in predicate

Tags: prolog

Lets assume I have facts as follows:

```
airport(nyc,'newyork').
```

I want want to display a message if the user inputs an airport that doesn't exist.

My Attempt:

```
isAirport(Air)  :-
      airport(Air,T),
     (var(T) -> true 
      ; 
       write('Airport not found'),
       fail
      ).
```

However, this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: if you query `airport(abc, _)` and `abc` is not an airport in the database, it will simply fail. You don't need to check the variable in the second argument. In fact, `airport(Air, T)` will fail and your `var(T)` will not even be called if `Air` is not an airport. Prolog has some very fundamental behaviors you need to learn before trying to write a full program. You should go through a good textbook and/or tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's see what happens if you query a conjunction (the , operator) first:

```
?- airport(nyc, _), write('found!').
found!
true.

?- airport(abc, _), write('found!').
false.
```

This means, `isAirport(abc)` directly fails after trying `airport(abc,_)` without the rest of your predicate being evaluated. In many cases, you can therefore get by without an explicit if-then-else construct and just write something of the form

```
predicate(X) :-
  first_condition(X),
  second_condition(X).
```

and it will only succeed if both conditions are fulfilled for `X`.

In case you really want to create some user interface, this is a bit more tricky, because I/O is inherently non-logical, in particular when there is backtracking involved. We usually call a program which behaves like we would expect from a logical formula pure and when it contains non-logical constructs like I/O or the cut operator `!` are called impure.

Unfortunately, the if-then-else construct (`->` and `;`) and negation (`\+`) are implemented via cut and therefore impure as well. Luckily, most of the time people want a conditional, a pure disjunction is sufficient:

```
case(1,a).
case(2,b).
```

We have an automatic branching from the execution mechanism of Prolog:

```
?- case(X,Y).
X = 1,
Y = a ;
X = 2,
Y = b.
```

But sometimes we really want to do something that needs the impure constructs, like user input. Then the easiest way to keep the nice logical properties of our program is to separate the task into pure and impure ones:

```
main :-
    uinput(Data),
    pure_predicate(Data, Result),
    write(Result).
```

After we have done all the impure parts, `Data` is unified with the user data we wanted. Let's have a look at the implementation of `uinput/1`:

```
uinput(data(Airport,D-M-Y)) :-
    format('~nAirport? '),
    read(Airport),
    ( ground(Airport), airport(Airport, _) )
    ->
        (
            format('~nDay? '),
            read(D),
            format('~nMonth? '),
            read(M),
            format('~nYear? '),
            read(Y),
            ( ground(D-M-Y), isDate(D-M-Y) )
        ->
        true
        ;
        throw(failure('unknown date'))
        )
    ;
    throw(failure('unknown airport'))
    .
```

We successively read terms from the input and throw an exception if we can't handle it. For the if-then-else construct to work, we need to take special care. If we compare the two queries:

```
?- between(1,3,X), write(X).
1
X = 1 ;
2
X = 2 ;
3
X = 3.
```

and

```
?- between(1,3,X) -> write(X); false.
1
X = 1.
```

you can see that the if-then-else is losing solutions. This means we need to make sure that our condition is deterministic. Asking for a user input term to be ground is already a good idea, because without variables, there is only one solution term. Still, a call to one of the data-predicates `airport/1` and `isDate/1` might generate the same term multiple times or not terminate at all. In this particular case, we just need to make sure that each airport has a unique shortcut name, we can also generate dates without repetition:

```
airport(nyc, 'New York City').
airport(wdc, 'Washington DC').

isDate(X-Y-Z) :-
    between(1,31,X),
    between(1,12,Y),
    between(1970,2100,Z).
```

Another trick in the implementation of `uinput` is that we just succeed with `true` when we have validated everything. The only effect of is now that `Data` is instantiated with whatever the user entered.

If we give a dummy implementation of the actual implementation, we can already try the implementation oursevles:

```
pure_predicate(_Data, Result) :-
    % here goes the actual stuff
    Result='we have found something awesome'.
```

On the prompt we can use the pure predicate without trouble:

```
?- pure_predicate(someinputdata,Y).
Y = 'we have computed something awesome'.
```

On the other hand, we can also use the full predicate as follows:

```
?- main(_).

Airport? wdc.

Day? |: 1.

Month? |: 2.

Year? |: 2000.
we have found something awesome
true.
```

Since we are using read, we have to input prolog terms and terminate with a dot `.`, but everything worked as expected.

In case the user input fails, we get:

```
?- main(_).

Airport? bla(X).

ERROR: Unhandled exception: failure('unknown airport')
```

Please note that we only went through this trouble to actually fail early and give a user message in that case. For the actual computation, this is completely unneccessary.

Answer (score 1):

In the code below you are making false assumption that T will remain unbound in case if airport will not be found in database:

```
airport(Air, T)
```

What happens actually is that call to airport(Air, T) will make isAirport(Air) to fail immediately and your var(T) and other parts will not be executed at all.

Try this code instead:

```
isAirport(Air) :-
    airport(Air, _T), ! ; write('Airport not found'), fail.
```

Comment: what is !?. I read the documentation online and found that ! cuts the predicated. Can you elaborate on the last statement?

Comment: Consider the query isAirport(nyc), that is, the query which should succeed because airport(nyc,'newyork') is in the database. When you run it, Prolog will find that 'nyc' is indeed in the database and will print 'true'. However, if you ask Prolog for more solutions (if you enter ";" in the console), Prolog will try to execute an alternative branch of isAirport(Air) definition, that is, "write('Airport not found'), fail" portion, and this is not what we want. Because of that we use !, which tells Prolog to stop searching for alternative solutions inside isAirport(Air).

Comment: Please keep in mind that this is very rough explanation of ! - I suggest to go through more elaborate tutorials of how ! works.

Comment: How about if I want to explore all the possible paths until a predicate returns false.  Here is my new problem: fly(Start,End) :- fly_helper(Start,End) , ! ; write('path not found'), nl, fail. What prolog will do is  get just one Start, End and then terminate. If I get rid of the statements following fly_helper, it displays all the possible paths. I want that, but I also want the error .